# Elasticsearch indexing mostly works, but periodically returns NewConnectionError

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm indexing a few hundred thousand records in Elasticsearch using its [Python client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html). It works most of the time, but will randomly fail in bursts. The indexing is in a loop, and while I should probably be using the bulk API, this is worrying because I don't want searches to fail.

Basically, the client fails to connect to the Elasticsearch server, resulting in:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

It's strange because if I catch this error and keep on indexing, I see that I get this error in bursts of a few hundred index attempts, then it starts working again. Then after a few minutes, I get another burst of failed index attempts, and so on.

I found someone getting the same error, and it seemed to be solved by adding `127.0.0.1 localhost` to their hosts file, as well as adding `127.0.0.1 <hostname>`. This didn't make any difference for me, I still get the error as described above.

I installed Elasticsearch through homebrew, and I installed Java 8 through homebrew as well.

What could be causing this? Could this be a bug in Elasticsearch?

Comment: Do you have anything in the logs? Also I would start to monitor the [thread pools](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html). And you should definitely use the bulk API.

Comment: Nothing in the logs. I do see the errors when they happen but there isn't anything when I fail to connect to the ES sever.

Comment: Also, yeah I'll look into thread pools. Are you suggesting this because maybe it's a GC "stop-the-world"?

Comment: GCs might come into play as well, but I was more interested in the queue depth of the `index` thread pool. I'd add some monitoring (such as [X-Pack Monitoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/xpack-monitoring.html), which is free to use) and take a look at the results. My Python experience is a bit too limited to say for sure, but are you certain this is not an issue on the Python side?

Comment: Not at all honestly. I'll look into X-Pack and see what I can find.